# how to find out driver process node for tasks running in spark in yarn-cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, driver

My spark is running in **yarn cluster** mode .When I submit a job , I want to find out which machine does the driver program locates in my cluster.
It seems that I can only get the container location from the yarn web ui:[image]

What can I do?

Comment: If you goto spark Web UI (by clicking on the Attempt ID column in the above image, then click on executors tab. The last row will usually be the driver. If this helps let me know, I'll add it as answere

Answer (score 0):

The Spark Web UI is launched on port 4040 of the driver node, so one way to find the driver's ip is to click on the logs link and search for `4040`

A sample log line would be `SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://10.100.0.117:4040` where `10.100.0.117` is the ip address of the driver node.

Comment: Yes , I know . But the problem is , my clustering has so many spark jobs running.